How to make click event on v-list-item occur after v-model on v-list updates
I have a v-list which contains a list of emails as shown:
    <v-list :disabled="selectedEmailLoading" v-model:opened="open" v-model:selected="selectedEmails" select-strategy="independent" color="primary" lines="two" item-props style="height: calc(100vh - 300px);">
      <template v-for="conversation in cleanFolder">
        <v-list-item v-if="conversation.length==1" v-for="email in conversation" class="rounded-lg py-5 my-2" :value="email" @click="loadEmail(conversation[0])">
          <template v-slot:prepend="{ isActive }">
            <v-list-item-action start>
              <v-avatar color="primaryLighten1">
                <span class="text-subtitle-1">{{email.from.email_address ? getStateAbbreviation(email.from.email_address) : ""}}</span>
              </v-avatar>
            </v-list-item-action>
          </template>
          <v-list-item-title class="d-flex justify-space-between mb-1">
            <div class="d-flex align-center" style="white-space: nowrap; word-break: normal; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
              {{ email.from.email_address }}
            </div>
            <div class="d-none d-md-flex align-center pl-5">
              <v-icon v-if="email.has_attachments" icon="mdi-paperclip" size="small"></v-icon>
            </div>
          </v-list-item-title>

          <v-list-item-subtitle class="d-flex justify-space-between">
            <div class="d-flex align-center" style="white-space: nowrap; word-break: normal; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
              {{ email.subject }}
            </div>
            <div class="d-none d-md-flex align-center pl-5 text-right" style="min-width:145px">
              {{ dayjs(email.received_date).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A') }}
            </div>
          </v-list-item-subtitle>
          <v-list-item-subtitle>
            <div class="mt-2" v-html="email.body_preview">
            </div>
          </v-list-item-subtitle>
        </v-list-item>
      <v-list>

When a user clicks the v-list-item it pulls additional information related to the email such as attachments and stuff then displays the email in another part of the screen. However, I am trying to update my v-model for the v-list selection to include this additional information for the email. The function I use is as follows:
     const loadEmail = async (email : Email) => {
     if(email.id != currentEmail.value?.id)
     {
      selectedEmailLoading.value = true    
      currentEmail.value = await emailStore.getEmail(activeMailboxLabel.value, email.id)
      // selectedEmails.value = selectedEmails.value.map((selectedEmail : Email) => {
      //   if (selectedEmail.id === email.id) {
      //       return currentEmail.value;
      //   }
      //   return selectedEmail;
      // });
      selectedEmailLoading.value = false
    }
  }

The commented section is where I am having trouble. Its almost as if the click event and my loadEmail function loads before the selectedEmails v-model variable updates. But overall I am trying to update the v-model array selectedEmails to include all the additional information in its respective node if the email is selected.

What about change to watch the v-model variable instead?

You can try to use nextTick:
import { nextTick } from 'vue'; // Import nextTick for Vue 3
...
const loadEmail = async (email: Email) => {
  // Ensure that the DOM updates have been applied
// use this.$nextTick if you are using vue2
  nextTick(() => {
    if (email.id != currentEmail.value ? .id) {
      selectedEmailLoading.value = true
      currentEmail.value = await emailStore.getEmail(activeMailboxLabel.value, email.id)
      // selectedEmails.value = selectedEmails.value.map((selectedEmail : Email) => {
      //   if (selectedEmail.id === email.id) {
      //       return currentEmail.value;
      //   }
      //   return selectedEmail;
      // });
      selectedEmailLoading.value = false
    }
  })
}


That does the trick!

That's how Vue is designed, $nextTick will be triggered after the DOM updates.
